# Partitioning $\{1,2,...,1998\}$ such that $|a_i-b_i|$ is $1$ or $6$

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, contest-math

> Suppose that the set $\{1,2,3,\cdots, 1998\}$ has been partitioned into disjoint pairs $\{a_i,b_i\}(1\le i \le 999)$ so that for all $i, \mid a_i-b_i\mid$ equals $1$ or $6$. Then the sum $\mid a_1-b_1\mid +\mid a_2-b_2\mid+\cdots +\mid a_{999}-b_{999}\mid$ = ?

I found this problem on AoPS. I found out that the answer is 999 by partitioning the set into $\{1,2\},\{3,4\}, ... , \{1997, 1998\}$, but I am not sure about the proper way of solving it

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Could you provide a link to where you found this? If it's https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/1998_USAMO_Problems/Problem_1 then note that the problem there is to show that the sum *ends in the digit* $9$.

Comment: I found it in a private forum @above

Answer (score 3):

Let $C$ be the number of Consecutive pairs in the partition, and $S$ be the number of pairs that differ by Six. We have $C+S=999$ and the sum of the differences is thus

$$C+6S=999+5S$$

Now each pair that differs by $6$ consists of either two odd numbers or two even numbers. It's easy to see that the first such pair must consist of two odd numbers and the last such pair must consist of two even numbers -- e.g., you can't have $\{2,8\}$ without having $\{1,7\}$. What's a little harder to see is that the pairs that differ by $6$ must *alternate* between both odd and both even (when ordered, say according to the smaller number in each pair), but this can be shown by induction. It follows that $S$ must be an even number. Every even value of $S$ is possible between $0$ and $996$: Start with the "dense" set of pairs that differ by $6$ that pairs the numbers $1$ through $6$ with $7$ through $12$, $13$ through $18$ with $19$ through $24$, etc., and then two at time change $\{1,7\}$ and $\{2,8\}$ to $\{1,2\}$ and $\{7,8\}$, then $\{3,9\}$ and $\{4,10\}$ to $\{3,4\}$ and $\{9,10\}$, etc. It follows that every number ending in a $9$, from $999$ to $5979$, is a possible sum.

Remark: If all one wants to show is that the sum, whatever it is, ends in a $9$ (which is what the original AoPS problem asks for), it's enough to note that $999+5S\equiv4$ mod $5$ and that the sum and difference of any two numbers have the same parity, so the parity of the sum of the differences is

$$1+2+\cdots+1998={1998\cdot1999\over2}=999\cdot1999\equiv1\mod2$$

and therefore (combining $4$ mod $5$ and $1$ mod $2$) the sum of the differences is $\equiv9$ mod $10$. (The [AoPS solution](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/1998_USAMO_Problems/Problem_1) gives a different argument for the $4$ mod $5$ part of the proof; I might have thought of the parity part myself, but I saw it there first.)

Answer (score 1):

You found the partition with the minimal possible such sum.
But whenever you have six consecutive distance-$1$ pairs $\{a,a+1\},\{a+2,a+3\},\ldots,\{a+10,a+11\}$, you can replace them with distance-$6$ pairs $\{a,a+6\},\{a+1,a+7\},\ldots, \{a+5,a+11\}$. This increases the distance sum  for these from $6$ to $36$. You can repeat this process for several groups of consecutive $12$ numbers.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer made me understand. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

(Previous incorrect answer removed.)

As $1 \equiv 6 \pmod 5$, $|a_i-b_i| \equiv 999\cdot1 \equiv 4 \pmod 5$.

For minimum sum, take pairs of consecutive numbers so that each $|a_i-b_i|=1$ and $\sum |a_i-b_i|=999$.

Next rearrange groups of $6$ consecutive pairs as in @Hagen von Eitzen's answer, to increase sum by $30$ per group.

As sum only increases by $30$, every possible sum ends in digit $9$.

Note as $1998$ is only multiple of $6$ and not $12$, not all $|a_i-b_i|$ can be $6$. For maximum sum, take distance-$6$ pairs upto largest multiple of $12$ which is $1992$, as $\{(1,7)(2,8),\ldots,(1991,1992)\}$ followed by $\{(1993,1994),(1995,1996),(1997,1998)\}$ to yield $$ \dfrac{1992}{2}\cdot6+3=5979$$